# Swift Combine doesn't update value by sink

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I want to achieve this: A class `A`, which has a property `var c1: C` and `var b1: B`, if the property of `C` changes, then the property of `b1` should be updated.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

struct B {
    var b = "b"
}

class C: ObservableObject {
    @Published var c: String = "c1"
}

class A: ObservableObject {
    var b1 = B()
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    @Published var c1 = C()

    init() {

        $c1.sink {
            print("new value is \($0.c)") //Only print once
            self.b1.b = $0.c
        }.store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    func printMe() {
        print("b1.b: \(b1.b)")
        print("c1.c: \(c1.c)")
    }
}



let a = A()
a.c1.c = "c2"
a.printMe()


a.c1.c = "c3"
a.printMe()
```

The output is:

```
new value is c1
b1.b: c1
c1.c: c2
b1.b: c1
c1.c: c3
```

Every time the `a.c1.c` was updated I expected `a.b1.b` should be updated automatically by `sink`, not sure if anything I missed, the `sink` closure body just was called once.

Any suggestion? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `@Published var c1 = C()` and `$c1.sink` you are observing changes to `A`'s property `c1`. This assignment does not change, since it is a reference type, so the sink is only called on initialisation.

Updating the sink to:

```
c1.$c.sink {
    print("new value is \($0)") //Prints every time! 
        self.b1.b = $0
    }.store(in: &cancellables)
```

Gives the behaviour you're looking for. I don't think the c1 publisher will emit any values in this scenario, but it's not clear what behaviour you're looking for there so I haven't gone into it.

Comment: My `C` class has more than 10 properties, if any of them updated I want to update to B class. In B just less than 5 properties which are all computed according to the properties of a. That is I want to do the calculation in the `sink` closure to assign every properties to B. Should I call `sink` on every properties of `C`? Any suggestion? thanks

Comment: uh, I think I can update `C` every time? let me try. If you know better solution please let me know, thanks a lot!

Comment: It might make more sense to have C have a published value of B, which changes when any of c's properties are updated. You can then observe that value. Observing the _assignment_ of C (which is what `@Published var c1 = C()` is setting up) seems like the wrong approach

Comment: Thanks for that, I was really struggling with .sink and hadn't used .store so only ever got one event received!!